# Google fonts isn't working on mozilla firefox 50 under windows and safari

Tags: html, css, google-font-api

Google Fonts isn't working on Mozilla Firefox 50 under Windows and Safari, but working in Firefox 51 under lLinux Ubuntu 16.04.

Here is my html and css. I'm not sure where is the problem. I can put more code if needed.

```css
.BreeSerif{font-family:"Bree Serif";}
.Abel{font-family:"Abel";}
.Vollkorn{font-family:"Vollkorn";} 
.Pacifico{font-family:"Pacifico";}
.Signika{font-family:"Signika";} 
.Alegreva{font-family:"Alegreva";} 
.Alegreya{font-family:"Alegreya";}
.Righteous{font-family:"Righteous";} 
.DancingScipt{font-family:"Dancing Scipt";}
.Chewy{font-family:"Chewy";}
.Questrial{font-family:"Questrial";} 
.SigmarOne{font-family:"Sigmar One";}
.JosefinSlab{font-family:"Josefin Slab";}  
.AbrilFatface{font-family:"Abril Fatface";} 
.CoveredByYourGrace{font-family:"Covered By Your Grace";} 
.GloriaHallelujah{font-family:"Gloria Hallelujah";} 
.LobsterTwo{font-family:"Lobster Two";} 
.Comfortaa{font-family:"Comfortaa";}
.SortsMillGoudy{font-family:"Sorts Mill Goudy";}
.Lato{font-family:"Lato";}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Covered+By+Your+Grace' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sorts+Mill+Goudy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<li class="content fontShape-options">
  <div class="select-wrapper font-style">
    <select id="fontFamily">
      <option class="BreeSerif" value="Bree Serif">Bree Serif</option>
      <option class="Abel" value="Abel">Abel</option>
      <option class="Vollkorn" value="Vollkorn">Vollkorn</option>
      <option class="Pacifico"value="Pacifico">Pacifico</option>
      <option class="Signika" value="Signika">Signika</option>
      <option class="Alegreva" value="Alegreva">Alegreya</option>
      <option class="Alegreya" value="Orbitron">Orbitron</option>
      <option class="Righteous" value="Righteous">Righteous</option>
      <option class="DancingScipt" value="Dancing Script">Dancing Script</option>
      <option class="Chewy" value="Chewy">Chewy</option>
      <option class="Questrial" value="Questrial">Questrial</option>
      <option class="SigmarOne"  value="Sigmar One">Sigmar One</option>
      <option class="JosefinSlab"  value="Josefin Slab">Josefin Slab</option>
      <option class="AbrilFatface"  value="Abril Fatface">Abril Fatface</option>
      <option class="CoveredByYourGrace" value="Covered By Your Grace">Covered By Your Grace</option>
      <option class="GloriaHallelujah" value="Gloria Hallelujah">Gloria Hallelujah</option>
      <option class="LobsterTwo" value="Lobster Two">Lobster Two</option>
      <option class="Comfortaa" value="Comfortaa">Comfortaa</option>
      <option class="SortsMillGoudy" value="Sort Mill Goudy">Sorts Mill Goudy</option>
      <option class="Lato" value="Lato">Lato</option>
    </select>

  </div>
```

Comment: I think it's simply a matter of FF not allowing option elements to be styled. If you add something like `<div class="SigmarOne">Sigmar One</div>` after the list, it works fine.

Comment: As for Safari, you are talking about Safari under Windows, right? That is an old version (v5, from 4½ years ago) which you can safely ignore. Safari is currently at v10.

Comment: I don't know it it helps, but the option elements are also styled under SeaMonkey. Not sure why SeaMonkey would do things differently than Firefox, but there you have it.

Comment: Mr Lister can you give me link to JSFiddle.

Comment: With your purpose for use div because i 'don't understand what is your idea.

Comment: Oh... Sorry, it was not a suggestion for a solution. I was trying to point out that the fonts work fine in a div, just not in a select. In other words, that the problem is Firefox doesn't allow selects to be styled, not that there is something wrong with your css or with the webfonts. Sorry to get your hopes up.

Comment: Ok i understand thanks for ideas i will try and if i have solution i will write here.